# Composer/Doctrine 2 Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit...' not found in vendor/autoload.php

Tags: doctrine-orm, composer-php, autoloader

This is driving me insane. Everything was moving along fine until I tried to change my composer.json file. Once I composer.update'ed I started getting this error in my log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInite904d9fc0cad6e1b28066897f772cc3f' not found in /home/apache2/htdocs/doctrine/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

I've changed composer.json back to the normal state and even went so far as to delete the entire directory and start over again. Absolutely nothing works.

Here's the autoload.php file.

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInite904d9fc0cad6e1b28066897f772cc3f::getLoader();
```

**UPDATE:**

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver locally to edit files on a remote Linux server.

I have recognized a pattern. I get this class error ONLY when I update a file that sits outside of my /src folder. For example, if I update src/Form.php, everything is fine on upload. If I update admin/access/formbuilder.php I get the Class error until I composer dump-autoload.

I just tried adding "admin/access/ to autoload in composer.json but that does not do the trick. Here is what the composer.json file looks like:

```
{
  "require": {
      "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
      "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "classmap":["src/", "admin/access/"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to provide that file (you mention that file is taken from a tutorial). This is automatically generated by Composer as part of the update process, and gets also generated during install. The name of the class is dynamically generated, and you will never match the current autoloader class name.

If you somehow committed that file in your own source control, then you should get rid of it. Don't use code that restores that file to a previous state.

Comment: Well ultimately I realized I did not take that specific file from a tutorial. However the last part of your response seems to solve the issue; when I turn off Dreamweaver's option to "Automatically upload files to server on Save" I stopped getting the errors. What puzzles me though is that the remote and local  vendor/autoload.php files are still the same even after several saves.

Comment: Where (which machine) is your Dreamweaver running, where are you running `composer dump-autoload`, and where is that error message originating from, and when?

Comment: Dreamweaver is running locally on my PC (Win7). `composer dump-autoload` is being run remotely on a Linux server. The error message is originating from that remote server's logs/error_log file. I just tried updating my composer.json file and I have begun getting the error about Class not found again. Even after changing the .json file back.

Comment: Ok, then here is what is happening: Dreamweaver sent his version of the file to the server. You were changing it on the server and generating a new ID, but Dreamweaver keeps overwriting it with the old ID. I have no idea why it does not overwrite the other file as well. You would have to run `composer update` or any other Composer command on the machine you have Dreamweaver running with this setup. Dreamweaver would then automatically send the correct files to the server.

Comment: I have recognized a pattern. I get this class error ONLY when I update a file that sits outside of my /src folder. For example, if I update src/Form.php, everything is fine on upload. If I update admin/access/formbuilder.php I get the Class error until I `composer dump-autoload`. I just tried adding `"admin/access/` to `autoload` in composer.json but that does not do the trick.